# How to determine http verb allowed on a .net function using ildasm

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs, ildasm, gac-msil

I have a .net DLL which has web api end points with http verb decoration. And I only have ildasm disassembler to view IL code. How can I check what http verb is allowed for an endpoint(a particular Controller Action method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. With Ctrl+M we can see the metada, and if there is any customised http decorator, only then we will find the name of decorator used under the Customized Header section. We can see the name of the decorator, may it be httpget, httppost etc.